# What is the specific sound law that describes the change from Proto-Indo-European "*h₂éǵros" to Latin "ager"?

Tags: morphology, proto-indo-european

Is there a rule for the movement of the "r" to the end of the word? Or is it moreso that there was some kind of intrusive "e" that separated the "-gr-" to form "-ger"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The development is the result of:

- syncope of *-gros to *-grs (with syllabic r, sometimes transcribed as *r̥ following a non-IPA convention). In Latin, the Proto-Italic sequences *-ros, *-ris often show syncope of the vowel after *r, with the r becoming syllabic when preceded by a consonant (as in *caper*) but not when preceded by a vowel (as in *vir, vesper*).

followed by

- loss of word-final s after r (most likely by assimilation *rs > *rz > *rr, followed by simplification of word-final *rr to /r/; for comparison, word-medial *rs became /rr/, as in *terra*)
- vowel epenthesis that ultimately turned *r̥ into /er/.

I'm not sure about the ordering of the two last bullets.

See the following posts on Latin SE:

- [Why do some 2nd decl. "-er" adjectives and nouns drop the "e" in the stem?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/377/why-do-some-2nd-decl-er-adjectives-and-nouns-drop-the-e-in-the-stem/382#382)
- [Does /l̥/ in reconstructed Latin represent a voiceless (alveolar) lateral approximate or something else?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13389/does-l%CC%A5-in-reconstructed-latin-represent-a-voiceless-alveolar-lateral-approx)

Further reading:

- [Comparative Grammar of Greek and Latin](https://ia802507.us.archive.org/21/items/BuckComparativeGrammer/CGL_text.pdf#page=115), 1933, Carl Buck, §109, pages 99-100

Answer (score 5):

Most sound changes don't have specific names.

A relevant point of comparison here is puer < *ph₂weros. This suggests that the masculine nominative singular thematic ending -os (as well as the vocative -e) was lost first, suggesting an intermediate form *agr which violates Latin phonotactics and so required the insertion of a vowel to make it legal. In most such instances Latin has i or u for epenthetic vowels, it seems likely that the choice of e here was influenced by some combination of analogy to puer (and similar words), the fact that an e already appears in the usual vocative ending, or some sort of vowel-colouring from the r (-ir and -ur being pretty unusual in Latin).

Comment: Are there any instances of epenthetic _i_ or _u_ before _r_? None come to mind, though I haven't gone looking. In fact I think _-ir_ and _-ur_ are pretty rare (apart from the passive of verbs, of course).

Comment: good point! I'll add that there may be some colouring from the r

Comment: Note also that short vowel reduction in Latin produced /i/ in most environments but /e/ before /r/: cap**e**ris, cap**i**tur. So coloring from the /r/ is very likely.

Answer (score 5):

Note that Latin *ager* inflects as *agri, agro, agrum, agro* (in the singular), so the transformation of the ending is specific to the nominative singular. It is a regular development of Latin, that *Crus becomes Cer.